# How do I add a class to a specific li element with React?

Tags: reactjs, class, onclick, state

I have this working todo list React app.

The state variable `tasks` contains objects, with a string for the task, and `done`, a boolean. I know how to add a class based on that boolean, but what I'm confused about is how to change that specific object's `done` variable using a click event.

Here's App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import v4 from 'uuid';

function App() {
  const [ tasks, setTasks ] = useState([{task: 'Test task',
                                         done: false},
                                         {task: 'other task',
                                         done: false},
                                         {task: 'blah task',
                                         done: false}])
  const [ formVal, setFormVal ] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTasks([...tasks, {task: formVal, done: false}]);
    // Todo: clear form after submit
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setFormVal(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleClick = e => {
    // This is probably a good place to use useReduce
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>To Do List</h1>
      <br />
      <ol>
        {
          tasks.map(item => (
            <li key={v4()} className={item.done ? 'done' : ''} onClick={handleClick}>{item.task}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ol>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Add a task   </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder='What to do?' onChange={handleChange}></input>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map can take 2 arguments where the second one is the index of the element you can send the index and then use that to retrieve the element and update it.

here is the changes i have made

```
const handleClick = index => {
    // This is probably a good place to use useReduce
    console.log(index);
    console.log(tasks[index]);
    let newTasks = [...tasks];

    newTasks[index] = { ...tasks[index], done: true };
    console.log(newTasks);
    setTasks(newTasks );
  };





<ol>
    {tasks.map((item, index) => (
      <li
        className={item.done ? "done" : ""}
        `enter code here`onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
      >
        {item.task}
        {/* to check the change */}
        {String(item.done)} 
      </li>
    ))}


  </ol>
```

Comment: sorry i did not understand the question properly but if you wish to clear all the tasks after they are done then you can make a function that loops over the array and check for the done status of each object and if it doesn't find any task's done status to false you can set your task array empty now you can fire this function manually on click of a button or put it after you change the task to done in your handleClick but it will fire everytime you change a task to done which hinders performance

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is to create a curried `handleClick` handler that takes an id and returns the function to be used as the callback. Use a functional state update to map previous state to a new array and toggle the `done` value when the id matches.

```
const handleClick = id => e => {
  setTasks(tasks => tasks.map(task => task.id === id ? {
    ...task,
    done: !task.done,
  } : task));
};
```

This requires your data to also have stable ids. As is, your code will generate new id/keys each time it is rendered, thus negating the purpose of react keys to begin with (*i.e. each render cycle each array element has a new key and the entire array will be rerendered*). Instead of generating the keys in the render array mapping, generate them when data is added to the tasks array.

Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import v4 from "uuid";

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    { task: "Test task", id: 'xxxxxx:xxxx:xx', done: false }, // <-- data has id field
    { task: "other task", id: 'yyyyyyy:yyyy:yy', done: false },
    { task: "blah task", id: 'zzzzzzz:zzzz:zz', done: false }
  ]);
  const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTasks([...tasks, { task: formVal, id: v4(), done: false }]); // <-- generate id when adding task
    // Todo: clear form after submit
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setFormVal(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleClick = id => e => {
    setTasks(tasks =>
      tasks.map(task =>
        task.id === id
          ? {
              ...task,
              done: !task.done
            }
          : task
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>To Do List</h1>
      <br />
      <ol>
        {tasks.map(item => (
          <li
            key={item.id} // <-- use item.id as key
            className={item.done ? "done" : ""}
            onClick={handleClick(item.id)} // <-- pass item.id to handler
          >
            {item.task}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Add a task </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="What to do?" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## Edit - Clearing Form on Submit

If you with to clear the input upon submission then make the input a controlled input, i.e. give it a `value`, and in the submit handler simply reset the value

```
...

function App() {
  ...
  const [formVal, setFormVal] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    setFormVal(''); // <-- clear form value
  };

  ...

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        ...
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="What to do?"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={formVal} // <-- set input value from state
        />
        ...
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your task object an id or something to identify it, for the moment we can take the task name as a non repetable value.
Add a [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) prop to your `li` such as

`<li data-task={item.task} onClick={handleClick} key={v4()}>`

Then in your `handleClick` you can access that with `e.target.dataset.task`, now you have the task name, filter through the state and change the `done` value!